# Error in adding user in RabbitMQ using Ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, rabbitmq

I am trying to create a rabbitmq node using terraform and ansible scripts,Other scripts are executing successfully but I am facing a warning while running this script of adding a user in rabbitmq node.
**[WARNING]: Module did not set no_log for update_password**

```
failed: [rabbit-node1] (item=admin) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl -q -n rabbit list_users",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "configure_priv": ".*",
            "force": false,
            "node": "rabbit",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "configure_priv": ".*",
                    "read_priv": ".*",
                    "vhost": "/",
                    "write_priv": ".*"
                }
            ],
            "read_priv": ".*",
            "state": "present",
            "tags": "administrator,admin",
            "update_password": "on_create",
            "user": "admin",
            "vhost": "/",
            "write_priv": ".*"
        }
    },
    "item": "admin",
    "msg": "Error:********@rabbit-node1.\n * Suggestion: start it with \"rabbitmqctl start_app\" and try again",
    "rc": 70,
    "stderr": "Error: rabbit application is not running on node rabbit@rabbit-node1.\n * Suggestion: start it with \"rabbitmqctl start_app\" and try again\n",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Error: rabbit application is not running on node rabbit@rabbit-node1.",
        " * Suggestion: start it with \"rabbitmqctl start_app\" and try again"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

main.yml file for Creating user in Rabbitmq node using ansible:

```
- name: add user
  rabbitmq_user:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    password: "{{ ADMIN_PASS }}"
    tags: administrator,{{item}}
    vhost: /
    configure_priv: .*
    write_priv: .*
    read_priv: .*
    state: present
  with_items:
  - admin
```